# Как удалить значения объектов из массива объектов, не мутирует массив

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста.
Есть массив объектов примерно такой

```
[
    {
        _id(pin):"5ef862486093772cb01ec48f",
        start(pin):-240,
        duration(pin):60,
        title(pin):"tgt",
        __v(pin):0,
    }
]
```

```js
const resault = fileTask.reduce((acc, el) => {
    acc = [...acc, el , delete el._id , delete el.__v];
    return acc;
  }, []);
```

Comment: что подсказать-то? Какой результат ожидается?

Answer (score 0):

В таком случаи у меня мутируется fileTask. Удаление как-то не подходит(((
Я сделал так, но не знаю верно ли, но теперь fileTask не мутируется

```
  const resault = fileTask.map((el) => {
let arr = [];
arr = [...arr, { start: el.start, duration: el.duration, title: el.title }];
return arr;
```

});
Грубо говоря, пересобираю новый массив и потом с ним работаю

Comment: неверно, в result у тебя стал массив массивов с одним элементом. arr тут вообще не нужен, убери его и возвращай объект сразу

Answer (score -1):

Ваш пример исходной структуры синтаксически неверен, я его немного подредактировал.

Если я правильно понял, можно так:

```js
const fileTask = [
    {
        _id:"5ef862486093772cb01ec48f",
        start:-240,
        duration:60,
        title:"tgt",
        __v:0,
    }
];

const resault = fileTask.reduce((acc, el) => {
  delete el._id;
  delete el.__v;
  acc.push(el);
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(resault);
```

Или так:

```js
const fileTask = [
    {
        _id:"5ef862486093772cb01ec48f",
        start:-240,
        duration:60,
        title:"tgt",
        __v:0,
    }
];

const resault = fileTask.map((el) => {
  delete el._id;
  delete el.__v;
  return el;
});

console.log(resault);
```